# IIS Logs do not show the message logged

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-logs

I am trying to log the entire exception to the IIS log in the following way:

```
   public void OnTransientFaultOccurred(object sender, RetryingEventArgs e)
    {
        _httpResponse.AppendToLog(string.Format("RetryCount:{0}", e.CurrentRetryCount));
        _httpResponse.AppendToLog(string.Format("NextRetryIn:{0}ms", e.Delay.TotalMilliseconds));
        _httpResponse.AppendToLog(string.Format("Exception:{0}",e.LastException));
    }
```

But the log only shows '...'.

Is there any limit in terms of how much data can be written to the log ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try: Make sure the advanced logging extension is enabled.

As per [Append custom value to IIS logs from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857452/append-custom-value-to-iis-logs-from-asp-net/3859472#3859472).

Comment: Even after enabling advanced logging I see '...' in the log.